# How to make a Jquery snippet only apply to some certain tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

I came across this snippet whose function is to wrap img tag with a span and make the image background image of the span. My question is, how can I make it only apply to a certain img tag or some img tags in a certain div?

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("img").load(function() {
    $(this).wrap(function(){
        return '<span class="image-wrap ' + $(this).attr('class') + '" 
            style="position:relative; display:inline-block; background:url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ') no-repeat center center; width: ' + $(this).width() + 'px; height: ' + $(this).height() + 'px;" />';
    });
    $(this).css("opacity","0");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy, just replace `$("img")` with different [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to run "wrapping" code on different set of images rather than all images on site. For example use `$(".extra img")` to target any img that is inside tag with class "extra" (class="extra").

It's a basic, trivial knowledge of jQuery - I advice you read through jQuery tutorials or better yet, use jQuery code school http://try.jquery.com/ to learn how to use jQuery.